# After updating Eclipse from Mars to 2020-09 and used same workspace, no local history

Tags: eclipse, svn, local, history

Local history not working anymore after I moved from Eclipse Mars to 2020-09. I copied the Workspace folder to the new PC with the new Eclipse 2020-09 and everything went well. I just now discovered that the local history is not working for projects that are part of SVN. Normal projects do have local history.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Tarek

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I had to increase the max file size of local history as shows in the snapshot below.